# In React how to get JSON data dynamically from multi level object using key name

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native

I have multi level json data like

```
const data = {
    level11: "l11",
    level12: { level21: "l21", level22: { level31: "l31", level32: "l32" } },
    level13: [{ level131: "a" }, { level132: "b" }]
  };
```

I can easily get value by using property like data.level11 and the output is "l11" etc.
but I have key name like "level11" or "level12.level22.level31" etc

for first level I can easily access value by using data["level11"] but n level value is not comming.

My solution is as following.

```
generateData = (data, key) => {
    if (!key.includes("."))
      return data[key];
    var p = key.split(".")[0];
    var ndata = data[p];
    if(!ndata) return;
    var newkey = key
      .split(".")
      .filter((o, i) => i !== 0)
      .join(".");
    return this.generateData(ndata, newkey);
  };
```

but it is not working on array values or object values

Is there any other way to get values by using key name.

```
export default function App() {
  const data = {
    level11: "l11",
    level12: { level21: "l21", level22: { level31: "l31", level32: "l32" } },
    level13: [{ level131: "a" }, { level132: "b" }]
  };
  generateData = (data, key) => {
    if (!key.includes("."))
      return data[key];
    var p = key.split(".")[0];
    var ndata = data[p];
    var newkey = key
      .split(".")
      .filter((o, i) => i !== 0)
      .join(".");
    return this.generateData(ndata, newkey);
  };
   
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <span>{this.generateData(data, "level12.level22.level31")}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: whats is your expected output  for const data = {
    level11: "l11",
    level12: { level21: "l21", level22: { level31: "l31", level32: "l32" } },
    level13: [{ level131: "a" }, { level132: "b" }]
  };

Comment: It should be a stringfy json or string

Comment: can you paste the output expected response?

Comment: "level11" => "l11"
"level12" => "{ level21: \"l21\", level22: { level31: \"l31\", level32: \"l32\" } }"
"level12.level22.level31" => "l32"

Comment: @vicky Can you elaborate on this: `but it is not working on array values or object values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion for this kind of a problem.

**Logic**

- Process Key: It will have 2 levels

  - Current Key
  - Rest of the path
- Clean current key of any path specific special characters but not all. You can have key name like `data-key`
- Loop over rest of the structure and get value

```js
function processKey(key) {
  const k = key.match(/([^.\[\]])+/g)[0]
  const index = key.indexOf(k) + k.length  
  return [k, key.substr(index)]
}

function getValue(key, data) {
  const [k, rest] = processKey(key)
  if (!!rest) {
    return getValue(rest, data[k])
  }
  return JSON.stringify(data[k])
}

const data = {
  level11: "l11",
  level12: { level21: "l21", level22: { level31: "l31", level32: "l32" } },
  level13: [{ level131: "a" }, { level132: "b" }],
  level14: [[[{level132: 'bla'}]]]
};

console.log(getValue('level11', data))
console.log(getValue('level12', data))
console.log(getValue('level12.level22.level31', data))
console.log(getValue("level13[0].level131", data))
console.log(getValue("level14[0][0][0].level132", data))
```

Comment: nice solution Rajesh but it is not working with the key name "level13[0].level131"

Comment: @vicky Nice problem. Took some time but was able to fix it. Please check the update and let me know if you have queries